# What is meant by a natural hat trick in hockey?

Tags: terminology, ice-hockey

While reading [this](http://www.nhl.com/gamecenter/en/recap?id=2014020226) article on NHL.com I noticed that they mentioned several times that Jori Lehtera recorded a natural hat trick.

I assume they say natural hat trick to contrast it to another type of hat trick, but I don't know of any other types of hat tricks.

I have only ever heard them say natural hat trick when talking about hockey so I assume it is specific to hockey.

What other types of hat tricks are there in hockey, and are they that different that a distinction is required?

Comment: Wikipedia has a listing of some common variations on hat tricks. The one you're most likely to hear, aside from natural hat trick, is the Gordie Howe hat track (a goal, an assist, and a fight). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hat-trick#Hockey

Comment: 3 goals scored by the same player consecutively

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A natural hat trick is when the three goals are scored consecutively. That is, nobody else from either team scores in between the goals.