# How many NHL natural hat tricks in a single period have been scored?

Tags: trivia, statistics, ice-hockey

How many natural hat tricks have been scored, with all of the goals occurring in the same single period, in NHL history?

Comment: The question doesn't ask for a list of all one-period natural hat tricks, only how many there have been, which should be a straightforward counting via a statistical database. That one answer has listed all of a small number doesn't make the question too broad.

Answer (score 3):

Only having [data for the 2017-2018 NHL season](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/20019/16112) at my disposal:

- 81 hat-tricks were scored throughout the season
- 13 were natural
- 6 natural hat-tricks were scored in a single period (46.15% of all natural hat-tricks)

  - [Jamie Benn](https://www.hockey-reference.com/boxscores/201804070LAK.html) (1st period)
  - [Radek Faska](https://www.hockey-reference.com/boxscores/201711280VEG.html) (2nd period)
  - [William Karlsson](https://www.hockey-reference.com/boxscores/201803180VEG.html) (2nd period)
  - [Jason Zucker](https://www.hockey-reference.com/boxscores/201711090MTL.html) (3rd period)
  - [Teuvo Teravainen](https://www.hockey-reference.com/boxscores/201711130CAR.html) (3rd period)
  - [John Tavares](https://www.hockey-reference.com/boxscores/201710280NSH.html) (3rd period)